# How can we prove that every sequence of $30$ elements from a set of three repeats a subsequence of length 3?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

How can we prove that for every series over $30$ elements(included $30$), there must be a **"sub" three element series** then will repeat itself? (Series's numbers are **only** $\{1,2,3\}$)

Example for a "sub" series that repeats itself $12121$ (**"121"** repeats) , $1111$ (**"111"** repeats).

Example for a good series: $12311122$

Well, this was a question from the exam, unfortunately I wasn't able to answer it. I thought of many ways to solve this, but I'm sure there's fast efficient way to solve this that I don't see. I would love to know how you would approach this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the pigeonhole principle:

- The sequence of length 30 contains 28 subsequences of length three.
- There are 27 <strike>_____ (you fill in the blank)</strike> possible subsequences of length three.

Comment: actually when I think about that problem again, I still haven't managed to understand what to fill in the blank.

Comment: Because if you have a sequence of length 10, you will have 8 subsequences of length three. Thus, this will hold true by pigeonhole principle. So it's kinda weird because the question insists only if the series length is 30 and above.

Comment: Then why did you check the question answered? For a sequence of length three there are three choices for the first entry, three for the second ...

Comment: So there are $28^{30}$ possible subsequences? I'm really confused Jyrki.

Comment: No. You can list all the possible subsequences of length three. They are $111,112,113,\ldots,321,322,331,332,333$. A total of $3\cdot3\cdot3=27$.

Comment: Thanks Jyrki! highly appreciated.